# How do you load a package locally in Lua?

Tags: load, lua

If I have a file called test1.lua

```
function print_hi()
   print("hi")
end
```

and I want to make the function available to another file called test2.lua, I write:

```
require 'test1'
function print_hi_and_bye()
   print_hi()
   print('bye')
end
```

But, now let's say I have a third function called test3.lua to which I want to expose print_hi_and_bye() but NOT print_hi().  If I require 'test2' I will have access to both the print_hi and print_hi_and_bye() functions.  How do I get around this and keep the functions of test1 local to test2 so that nothing else uses them by mistake?  Is there a way to do this with lua's loading facilities and not just by refactoring code?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make `test1.lua` functions only visible for whom requested it. For this, some changes in files `test1.lua` and `test2.lua` are needed:

**test1.lua**

```
local pkg = {}
function pkg.print_hi()
    print("hi")
end
return pkg
```

**test2.lua**

```
local m = require 'test1'
function print_hi_and_bye()
    m.print_hi()
    print('bye')
end
```

The changes are minimal, and now you can use the functions only in the files you request them.

In Lua 5.1, you can use the [module](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-module) function in `test1.lua` for convenience.

```
module("test1")

function print_hi()
    print("hi")
end
```

In Lua 5.2, this function is deprecated as it [violated the design principles of Lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MechanismNotPolicy); instead you should do as shown in the first example.